# lineinfile/regexp/line: why line at the end of file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I don't understand how lineinfile works, I use:

```yaml
    - name: "configure"
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
        regexp: '^\/\/      "\${distro_id}:\${distro_codename}-updates";'
        line: '      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";'
        state: present
```

And I expect that line in file will be uncommented:

```
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
```

instead of this, this line stay as it is, but at the end of file,
I see:

```
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
```

so "match" happens, but why there is new line at the end of file instead of replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexp does not escape all of the special symbols and therefore there is no match which causes the addition of the new line instead of the replacement. Curly braces should be escaped, according to [Python's re module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

This task works as expected on my Ubuntu 18.04 server.

```
- name: "configure"
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
    regexp: '^//\s+"\$\{distro_id\}:\$\{distro_codename\}-updates";'
    line: '       "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";'
    state: present
```

Diff

```
-// "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
+   "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be other problem. The code works as expexted

```
shell> diff 50unattended-upgrades 50unattended-upgrades.orig 
1c1
<       "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
---
> //      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
```